# FancyBox custom close button

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I want to set up buttons types that can close the window, so I made wrote this code:

```
$(".fstandard").fancybox({
    afterClose: function() {
        alert("Closed!");
    },
    afterShow : function() {
        $(':button').click(function() {
            $.fancybox.close();
        })
    }
});
```

I tried in vain several other codes, but none of them worked, the window does not close. This line gives me an error:

```
$.fancybox.close();
```

> $.fancybox is undefined

I use FancyBox v2.0.3. In their documentation, it is well presented to close the window: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#support

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tried the other variants? `$(".fstandard").close()` or `$(".fstandard").fancybox.close()` ?

Answer (score 15):

It says in the documentation:

> To use from inside the iframe - `<a href="javascript:parent.$.fancybox.close();">Close me</a>`

Have you tried:

```
$(':button').click(function() {
    parent.$.fancybox.close();
})
```